# Is there any other way to animate 2d spritesheet without Animator Component in unity?

Tags: animation, unity, spritesheet

Is there any easy way exists that animates frames without using Animator component?

Comment: Why didn't you want to use the Animator?

Comment: Another way. Just information sharing.@Evorlor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here is the basic scrip I wrote with some help of anonymous somewhere on the internet. Script contains some of his code. Well, anyone can use it. I will improve it by time.

Here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AnimationScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Animate Once?")]
    [Tooltip("Either animation should run once or not.")]
    // Either animation should run once or not
    public bool
        _animateOnce = false;
    [Header("Time")]
    [Tooltip("Time in seconds to change frames.")]
    // Time in seconds to change frames
    public float
        _time = 1.0f;
    [Header("Sprites")]
    [Tooltip("Animation sprites.")]
    // Animation sprites
    public Sprite[]
        _sprites;

    int frameCount = 0;
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    void OnEnable ()
    {
        frameCount = 0;
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer> () as SpriteRenderer;
        StartCoroutine ("Animate");
    }

    void OnDisable ()
    {
        frameCount = 0;
        StopCoroutine ("Animate");
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        frameCount = 0;
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer> () as SpriteRenderer;
        StartCoroutine ("Animate");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator Animate ()
    {
        if (frameCount >= _sprites.Length) {
            if (_animateOnce) {
                yield break;
            } else {
                frameCount = 0;
            }
        }
        if (_sprites [frameCount] == null)
            yield break;

        spriteRenderer.sprite = _sprites [frameCount];
        frameCount++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (Mathf.Abs (_time));
        StartCoroutine ("Animate");
    }

    public void StopAnimation ()
    {
        StopCoroutine ("Animate");
    }
}
```

**Any suggestions are always welcome.**