# Setting up sequential animation clips in Unity

Tags: unity, mecanim

I'm trying to play two animation clips sequentially using Unity 2D. I've been using Mecanim for this so I've imported the two clips in a newly created controller and connected the first one to the next one. I also want the last clip to be looping so I set that toggle in the settings of the clip.
Now for some reason the first clip is played just fine but the second one doesn't animate at runtime. It loops fine in the Animator window and the clip itself works in the preview window but not at runtime.

I've also tried setting it up using the Animation Component and use the PlayQueued method but this doesn't give any animation.

I'm kind of lost on what to try next

EDIT: This is to be used on a Canvas UI Image

Answer (score 1):

You can just setup a transition between the two animations like so:

[image]

So in this above example, once the RedBlink animation is done playing once, it will automatically start playing RedAngry animation.

Make sure to only set the Loop Time on the animation that you want to loop.

[image]

Comment: Unity man :D (Y)

Comment: BTW I never tried this like this, if it really works then good answer bro

Comment: @HamzaHasan Really?  Maybe you should reply with your method.  It would be interesting to see how you do it.

Comment: @Jon I tried this and it gives me the same result. The first clip plays just fine and the second one goes into the loop but the animation on the screen seems to stop at the last frame of the first clip (+ see edit, I need this to work on a Canvas UI Image)

Comment: @Dries Are you sure that second animation is not bugged?   Can you play it manually?

Comment: @Jon for these type of customized animation I used to use my own created class for that, unlimited flexibility :). [See this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113345/is-there-any-other-way-to-animate-2d-spritesheet-without-animator-component-in-u) with [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/documentation.php)(optionally)

Comment: @Jon I created a new Animation Clip from my spritesheet by dragging it in the scene and saving it. I selected the Clip in the Project window and looked at the preview and it plays fine with the GameObject that was created in the scene when I dragged the spritesheet. So, I assigned this Clip to my controller and it just stops working

Comment: Is it possible that the Speed is set to 0?

Comment: Nope, both are default 1.

Comment: Can you post your code that sets the animation parameters?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ZmIp4 Here's a link to some screenshots. I hope this is what you want to see. Other then that I didn't do anything. The animation just starts when the GameObject gets activated automatically

Comment: Can you show me the inspector when you click on that Transition Arrow?

Comment: http://imgur.com/Eq77l6W Here it is

Comment: @Jon No more ideas?

Comment: It looks good to me... My guess is, that the Canvas element is mucking up your animation somehow.  Try setting the animation outside of the canvas area and see if it works.

Comment: @Jon I tried that and for some reason it's now the first state that's not showing up properly... This shit with Unity... I really don't know anymore now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36233/discussion-between-jon-and-dries).

Comment: May be you'd like to [do it manually](http://www.hamzahasan.com/2d-sprite-animation-unity/)

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animation))]
public class VAB_AnimationTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnimationClip[] clips;
    public bool loop = true;

    private Animation _anim = null;


    void Start()
    {
        _anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();

        QueueClips(clips);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!_anim.isPlaying && loop)
            QueueClips(clips);
    }

    void QueueClips(AnimationClip[] animclips)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < animclips.Length; i++)
        {
            _anim.AddClip(animclips[i], animclips[i].name);
            _anim.PlayQueued(animclips[i].name, i == 0 ? QueueMode.PlayNow : QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
        }
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it included some text or comments to explain what this code does and how it solved the problem.

Comment: Oh man !!! I'm ever so sorry that i posted a simple answer to animation sequencing in unity and it did not suit your needs.  But all the code does is move through a sequence of animation clips by populating the animation queue.  It will loop back if you set loop = true

Comment: Great, edit that into the answer and we can delete these comments so the answer stands on its own.